# Contactform7: display results from CURL

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I am stuck into a problem.

I sent contact form data through curl and I get a response from an API. How is it possible to display there results on my page? Ideally through AJAX and in my own custom div ?

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($contact_form) { // Run code after the email has been sent 
  $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        if ($posted_data['type'] == 'var1')
        {

            APIcurl(.....);

        }

    }

});

function APIcurl($var...)
{
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL =>  'https [...]

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

How to show the response on my page ? I tried this but it was not successfull : 

`document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    alert('');
    alert('test');
}, false );

}`

Many thanks in advance

EDIT : maybe is the solution to add an "add_action" after the API function such as : add_action('wp_footer'... but I don't know how I can display the results of the API function in this.

Comment: try `wpcf7submit` instead of mail sent.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work also. :-/

Comment: Your JS as written won't work - you would have to have it wrapped in <script> tags. Instead, try `print_r($response)` to see what response you're getting, and then you'll be able to parse however you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I removed the script tags in my post, sorry :)
If I put a print_r or somthing like echo 'test'; I cannot see the confirmation message of CF7. It displays only the arrows which are turning around.

The thing is, how can be able to display the response where I want?

Comment: I tested also with this, but it occurs nothing:
          add_action('wp_footer',  function() {
     ?>
     <!--API -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    alert('<?php /* print_r(json_decode(json_encode($response), true, 3));*/ ?>');
    alert('message envoye');
      <?php /* if ( '123' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
     ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );
    } */ ?>
   }, false );
   </script>

   <?php
     });